# What is the Windows equivalent of "wc -l"?

Tags: windows, command-line

What is the Windows equivalent of the Linux/Unix command `wc -l`?

Basically, how do you count the number of lines output from a command on the Windows command line?

Comment: You could also use the GnuWin32 tools and actually have `wc` (well, `wc.exe` ...) http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 158, accepted):

The Linux/Unix "line count" command, `wc -l`, has a Windows equivalent `find /c /v ""`.

#### How does this work?

According to [Raymond Chen](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/Raymond+Chen+-+MSFT) of the [The Old New Thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110825-00/?p=9803), this functions as such since

> It is a special quirk of the `find` command that the null string is treated as never matching.

The inverted (`/v`) count (`/c`) thus effectively counts all the lines;
hence, the line count.

#### Example usage

**To count the number of modified files in a subversion working copy:**

```
svn status -q | find /c /v ""
```

Such a command can be used to mark a build as "dirty" if the count is not `0`, i.e. there are uncommitted changes in the working copy.

**To obtain a line count of all your Java files:**

```
(for /r %f in (*.java) do @type "%f") | find /c /v ""
```

The command `find /c /v ""` can also be added to a batch file if required. 
Remember to duplicate the `%` characters (`%%f`) in batch files.

---

**PowerShell**

A working PowerShell equivalent is `Measure-Object -line` — some additional formatting is required though, e.g. a directory listing for simplicity:

```
(ls | Measure-Object -line).Lines
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Created a gist for reference - https://gist.github.com/a4ede7054b2ce5ee2708dd49bbd5a1a1

Comment: find.exe lives in "Windows\System32" if your Path has another 'find' you will need to profile the path.

Comment: This worked for me using triple quote as in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1269470/1268619) i.e. `ls | find /c /v """"""`

Comment: `(ls | Measure-Object -line).Lines`, exactly what I was looking for ;), and @pjpscriv, for me `ls | find /c /v """"""` does not work since it does not count only files but also all empty lines and tables header around, while `Measure-Object` method actually gives me 28 where I have 28 files, `findstr` method gives me 37 (file lines + extra lines).

Answer (score 49):

In PowerShell, to obtain a line count of all your java files:

```
type *.java | Measure-Object -line
```

Comment: welcome to superuser: - the question was about CMD not powershell, if you can answer the OP please edit your answer. these may help [answer], [ask], [help] again welcome to superuer and i hope you return, thankyou

Comment: Thanks @mic84. The question is about Windows command line. And Microsoft is trying to replace CMD with PowerShell:   https://www.networkworld.com/article/3143196/windows/microsoft-is-replacing-the-cmd-prompt-with-powershell.html  So this is a quite useful answer.

Comment: This inspired me to try adding this to my `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` file:  `function wc () { Measure-Object -c -l -w  }` (it did not work as expected.)

Answer (score 2):

Use "Count":

```
(Get-AppXPackage|?{!$_.InstallLocation}).Count
(ls).Count
```

Answer (score -1):

findstr /n /r .

This is a limited regex, so /n shows the line number of the match, and "." is match any char.

Comment: The question isn’t how to display the file with line numbers; the question is how to determine *the number of lines* in the file.

Comment: Look at the number of the last line, and that's how many lines are in the file.  The "find" command works, too, but maybe findstr will be useful in some cases.  I have found it to be.

Comment: That’s not a very user-friendly answer, especially given that we’ve received a couple of other answers that are more direct.  But, if that’s your answer, then please [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: the point is for automation scripting. No scripts will "look" at the line number to store the number of lines in a variable for further computation. And flooding the screen with unnecessary information lines and wasting CPU cycles are definitely not good