# error of "FIND: Parameter format not correct" in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

i'm getting an error of "FIND: Parameter format not correct" in powershell

The following works from CMD

```
C:\Users\User>echo abc | find "a"
abc

C:\Users\User>echo abc>z.z

C:\Users\User>find "a" z.z

---------- Z.Z
abc

C:\Users\User>
```

But this fails from powershell!

```
PS C:\Users\User> echo abc | find "a"
FIND: Parameter format not correct
PS C:\Users\User> echo abc >z.z
PS C:\Users\User> find "a" z.z
FIND: Parameter format not correct
PS C:\Users\User>
```

There is a similar question here ["FIND: Parameter format not correct" and "FINDSTR: Write error" with Pipes](https://superuser.com/questions/983105/find-parameter-format-not-correct-and-findstr-write-error-with-pipes)  where the answer says to use quotation marks with the find command. Though I have   And I wouldn't be using /C because i'm not trying to count occurrences. Though find /c isn't working either

```
PS C:\Users\User> find /C "a" z.z
FIND: Parameter format not correct
PS C:\Users\User>
```

And it's not a UK keyboard issue, where two pipe characters get swapped. 'cos it works in cmd and not powershell. And I tried copy/pasting the correct pipe character from charmap.  And as yo see this occurs also with the format of find [pattern] file. So without any pipe. So, not a pipe issue.

There's something about powershell and find, that is going wrong here. Where cmd is fine.

**Added**

Upon further investigation

```
PS C:\Users\User> which find
/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/find
PS C:\Users\User>
```

Makes me wonder, is that a PATH problem it's clashing with cygwin?

I don't think it's a PATH problem, because that's just cygwin's way of stating that the path is in c:\windows\system32  but does look like a weird clash with cygwin though in some way.. not sure if relevant to the problem.

It is running windows FIND

```
PS C:\Users\User> find /?
Searches for a text string in a file or files.

FIND [/V] [/C] [/N] [/I] [/OFF[LINE]] "string" [[drive:][path]filename[ ...]]

  /V         Displays all lines NOT containing the specified string.
  /C         Displays only the count of lines containing the string.
  /N         Displays line numbers with the displayed lines.
  /I         Ignores the case of characters when searching for the string.
  /OFF[LINE] Do not skip files with offline attribute set.
  "string"   Specifies the text string to find.
  [drive:][path]filename
             Specifies a file or files to search.

If a path is not specified, FIND searches the text typed at the prompt
or piped from another command.
PS C:\Users\User>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine:

```
write-host "abc" | find "`"a`""
```

In Powershell, its better using `Select-String`:

```
Write-host "abc" | Select-String "a"
```

Comment: thanks, and this worked with your quoting  `echo abc | find "\`"a\`""`   can you explain what's going on there?!

Comment: Cmd.exe and Powershell.exe renders and executes the command differently, while in Powershell quotes don't  get applied

Comment: alright but what does the backtick thing do exactly.. so you have  `\`"a\`"` (and then that strange thing , in double quotes  `"\`"a\`""`

Comment: Backtick escapes the double quote inside another double quote

Comment: but why does `dir "a.a"` work (with unescaped double quotes), and `echo "aa"` works(with unescaped double quotes). But not find with unescaped double quotes?

Comment: There those double quotes are not enclosed inside another double quotes, so they don't need escaping

Comment: thanks, but why would I even need two sets of double quotes, to use find in powershell?!

Comment: Your select-string line doesn't really seem to work because `Write-host "abc" | Select-String "z"`  outputs the same as `Write-host "abc" | Select-String "a"`. Both output `abc`