# List and count directories that don't contain a specific file

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch

I have a folder with many subfolders in it. Each of these subfolders may or may not contain a file named "George.txt".

This command (in a batch file)

```
for /d %%A in (*) do @if not exist "%%~fA\George.txt*" echo %%~fA
```

finds all the subfolders where "George.txt" doesn't exist and outputs a list in the cmd window like this:

```
D:\Folder\S1
D:\Folder\S5
D:\Folder\S11
```

Now I also need to know the total number of subfolders where "George.txt" doesn't exist. Either by appending numbers to each line:

```
1. D:\Folder\S1
2. D:\Folder\S5
3. D:\Folder\S11
```

or displaying a total at the end of the list, I have no preference:

```
D:\Folder\S1
D:\Folder\S5
D:\Folder\S11
Total: 3
```

Is something like this possible natively? I'm using Win 7 Ultimate x64.

Comment: How about counting the output lines?
See https://superuser.com/a/959037/263
Specifically`find /c` can count output lines.

Comment: Sounds good, but how to incorporate it to the command? All I manage to get is "1", "1", "1" every line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this

```
set /a nCount=0
for /d %%A in (*) do (
  @if not exist "%%~fA\George.txt*" (
    set /a nCount+=1
    echo %%~fA
  )
)
echo Total %nCount% folder(s) found
```

Comment: Great, thank you!